# How to remove previous selected option when selecting new option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Task:**

To create dropdown list with options, and will reflect selected option based on selection.

**Issue**

Have managed to create the dropdown list and also the syntax to display the selected option. However, I am facing an issue, whereby, when user were to select "Option1", "Option_1" will be displayed and when the user continues to select "Option2", "Option_2" will also be displayed ontop of "Option_1". "Option_1" will not be remove and only "Option_2" will be displayed. Hence, if the user is to select all 5 options, user will see all 5 options being displayed and not the latest option being displayed.

I have tried using `$("(id_name)").empty()` in my `function val(x)` and when I do that, none of the option selected is being displayed.

**Code:**

```
<script>
function val(x)
{
    if (x =="Others" )
    {
            document.getElementById("extradiv").style.display ="block";           
    }
    else if (x =="Name 1")
    {
            document.getElementById("Name1").style.display = "block";
    }else if (x =="Name 2")
    {
            document.getElementById("Name2").style.display = "block";
    }else if (x =="Name 3")
    {
            document.getElementById("Name3").style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

Dropdown list code:

```
<p>
<select name ="Agency" id="AgencyDetails" onchange = "return val(this.value);">
<option value ="0" selected = "selected"> Select Agency..</option>
<option value ="Name 1"> Bob</option>
<option value ="Name 2"> Amanda</option>
<option value ="Name 3"> Gen</option>
<option value = "Others"> Others</option>
</select>
</p>
```

ExtraDiv code:

```
<div id = "extradiv" style ="display:none">
                    <li>
                            <label>Person Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="fieldInput" id="Name" value="" title="Address" />

                    </li>
                    <li>
                            <label>Name Registration Number:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="fieldInput" id="nameCompanyAddress" value="" title="Address" />

                    </li>
                    <li>
                            <label>Name Address:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="fieldInput" id="nameCompanyAddress" value="" title="Address" />

                    </li>
</div>
```

Name1:

```
<div id = "Agency1" style ="display:none">
            <li><label>Name:</label>Name1

            </li>
            <li><label>Name Registration Number:</label>Name Registration Num 1
            </li>
            <li><label>Name Address:</label>Name Address 1
            </li>
            </div>
```

Hence, Name1 and Name2 and Name2 format are the same.

Can anyone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
function val(x) {
    document.getElementById("extradiv").style.display = x == "Others" ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("Name1").style.display = x == "Name 1" ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("Name2").style.display = x == "Name 2" ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("Name3").style.display = x == "Name 3" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked. Whats the difference between what I have done and what you have proposed>